# What is the best Responsive Lightbox or Modalbox like facebook or instagram?

Tags: jquery, facebook, lightbox, instagram, image-gallery

I want to display images with comments and descriptions in a gallery just like facebook and instagram does.
What is the best jquery plugin for this?

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple to accomplish actually.  Basically you want to load a div rather than a traditional image lightbox.

Something like http://buckwilson.me/lightboxme/ where the image is wrapped in a div with comments + image information in another div side-by-side.

Another option is something like this http://www.picssel.com/playground/jquery/fancyboxALAfacebook_26Mar12.html using fancybox.

Comment: but whats the code for the gallery and fullscreen mode?
Because I found this plugin: https://github.com/MikeSilvis/mikes-modal-library but I want to make it a gallery and have fullscreen mode :)

Comment: I would highly recommended checking out the source code for jetpack's carousel. Demo: http://jetpack.me/support/carousel/ Source: https://github.com/Automattic/jetpack/tree/master/modules/carousel with most of the important info here: https://github.com/Automattic/jetpack/blob/master/modules/carousel/jetpack-carousel.js

Not sure how good you are with coding/js but I think it should help. I'll continue to look for something that is more complete.

Comment: Checkout magnificent lightbox - http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/ and this demo of something similar to what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/ceqLJ/

and this thread on the issue of responsiveness http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17475599/responsive-lightbox